# “Who are you known to”

Tags: passive-voice

My English teacher asked me to construct the passive voice of the sentence "*Who knows you?*". Then, I could immediately make up the sentence "*To whom are you known?*". My English teacher said that it was absolutely correct.

But she constructed another sentence: "*Who are you known to?*". I could understand that the sentence is grammatically correct as the preposition "to" is at the end now, and the interrogative pronoun "who" is not a prepositional object. But still I could not appreciate that the meaning of the second sentence should be as clear as the first one. How should I understand "1. Who, are you know to?" and "2. Who are you, known to?"?  I could not make out the meaning of the sentence "Who are you known to?".

Please explain the reasoning leading to  the right  interpretation.

Comment: Why would your English teacher want you to do that? Questions that focus on the subject are not to be passivized, because the passive construction makes the subject optional, and adds complex syntax while confusing the question.

Answer (score 1):

> who knows you?
> To whom are you known?
> Who are you known to

The  passive form is"*By whom are you known?*"; there is a confusion between the verbal forms " to be known by" and "to be known to somebody" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+is+known+to+him%2Cit+is+known+to+me%2Cit+is+known+to+them&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20known%20to%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20known%20to%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20known%20to%20them%3B%2Cc0), [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+known+to+him+that%2Cis+known+to+me+that%2Cis+known+to+them+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20known%20to%20him%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20known%20to%20me%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20known%20to%20them%20that%3B%2Cc0)). In this second form the verb is not transitive and it does not mean  "identify"; instead it is intransitive and means "have understanding or knowledge" (SOED (**III 9**)).

- It has been known to them for some time that the earth is not flat.
- Those facts are known to the owner.
- — To whom are those facts known? — To the owner.

The rule of passage from the active to the passive form is given in the following diagram.

[image]

From *A comprehensive grammar of the English language*, § **3.65**

Comment: My question is that "who are you known to?" is correct passive voice for the sentence "who knows you?". Since my English teacher had a debate that it is correct but I could not understand the meaning of the sentence clearly. Please kindly explain how to interpret the meaning. Thank you for reply

Comment: @RAVIVARMA Your question is founded on a wrong assumption; you believe that the passive form of "who knows you?" is "To whom are you known?"; that is not correct, and your teacher goes to far because she changes "by" into "to"; you can't do that because there is no alternative. So the correct form is ""By whom are you known?". If "to" replaces "by" the meaning of the verb is changed. All of that has been said in my answer, but if something is still not clear ask for more details.

Comment: @RAVIVARMA John knows Mary.  ↔  Mary is known by John.